# Database only adds (x) amount of rows before error system resources exceeded

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am having a problem with my code where i am only able to add so many lines of text before i get an error "system resources exceeded".

This is my code:

```
Dim x As Integer = MsgBox("Update Record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Are you sure?")

    If x = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Dim accessconn As New  _
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "MyDB.accdb")
        Dim com As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        accessconn.Close()
        Try
            For Each strLine As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
                accessconn.Open()
                Dim str As String
                Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
                str = "SELECT * FROM Table4 WHERE MD5='" & strLine & "'"
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, accessconn)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If dr.Read() Then
                    Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1
                Else
                    accessconn.Open()
                    com = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table4(MD5) VALUES('" & strLine & "')", accessconn)
                    com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                    Label3.Text = Label3.Text + 1
                    com.Dispose()
                    accessconn.Close()
                End If
            Next
            accessconn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        MsgBox("Done")
        PopulateGridview4()
    End If
```

I would like to be able to add unlimited rows of text to the database if possible. Please Help.

Comment: Your `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand`, and `OleDbReader` all need to be in `Using` blocks to clean up resources.

Comment: Could you give an example please as i am new to using vb.net and/with databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code to something like the following. Note that

1. Everything that returns an object like `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand`, or `OleDbDataReader` is wrapped in a `Using` block. These objects all implement the `IDisposable` interface, which means they should be cleaned up as soon as you're done with them.
2. Also note that your `INSERT` did not return any data, so you should use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader`.
3. Finally, please don't get into the habit of putting `Try/Catch/End Try` blocks around everything. You were displaying the exception (you displayed `ex.ToString`, which is a *good thing*), but you then ignored the exception. As a good general rule, don't catch exceptions unless you can fix them.

Code:

```
Dim x As Integer = MsgBox("Update Record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Are you sure?")

If x = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    Using accessconn As New  _
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "MyDB.accdb")
        accessconn.Open()
        For Each strLine As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
            Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM Table4 WHERE MD5='" & strLine & "'"
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, accessconn)
                Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    If dr.Read() Then
                        Label2.Text = Label2.Text + 1
                    Else
                        Using com As OleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table4(MD5) VALUES('" & strLine & "')", accessconn)
                            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End Using
                        Label3.Text = Label3.Text + 1
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
        MsgBox("Done")
        PopulateGridview4()
    End Using
End If
```

P.S. you could probably have made this a little less indented by using `If x <> MsgBoxResult.Yes Then` *get out*, but I don't know if this is inside of a `Sub` or `Function`, so "*get out*" could be different.

Comment: Thank you very much i will try this when i get back from work tonight and get back to you. Thanks again .

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you should remove the check-mark!

Comment: This worked great just had to remove the second    accessconn.Open() thanks again @JohnSaunders

Comment: Just one more question, when i fill the textbox with say 400,000 lines this still works but is really really slow would there be a faster way of adding large text files to the database?

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way, but I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Also, that would be a separate question. Among other things, learn to use parameterized queries. Beyond that, you should do a performance analysis on the code to see where it spends it's time - then make it spend less time there. If it's very slow very often, then you may want to learn about the T-SQL `MERGE` statement. You can play fancy tricks with passing a block of XML with your lines to a stored procedure which would call `MERGE` to insert those lines not already present

Comment: But if it's only slow once a week, then just use parameterized queries and leave it at that.